# Rails: Modeling a list that can contain both items and lists

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model, nested, hierarchy

I can't wrap my head around modeling a particular sort of list in Rails.

Basically, I'd like to model a list whose members contain other lists or individual items.

Let's say I have a table of car parts

```
Table Part
name
cost
color
```

Let's say that some lists of parts are very common so I want to define some lists of parts and reuse those lists.  For instance:

```
Table PartList
name

Table PartListItem
part_id
partList_id
position
```

Now, if I want show the items needed for a particular car, I'd like a list whose members may be items particular to a given car and members that are a list of commonly bundled items that can be found in many cars.

Might look like this:

Parts List For Modest car:
 - List of parts for engine
 - List of parts for body
 - front bumper
 - back bumper
 - tail pipe
 - List of parts for safety compliance

Parts List For Fancy car:
 - List of parts for engine
 - List of parts for body
 - Shiny front bumper
 - Shiny back bumper
 - Wizbang tail pipe
 - List of parts for safety compliance

If I were to modify the list of parts for 'engine' a view into either car part list would reflect the change. Regardless of the hierarchical level of the list, the list may contain more lists or individual items.

Once all lists are 'expanded' their contents are all 'Parts'

I may be wrong, but this is not exactly recursion, not exactly a tree, and not exactly nested sets.  Feels a little like a menuing system to me, but each member of the 'menu' may have many attributes.

Is there a DRY solution for this sort of problem?  I'd be happy to accept some, uh... lack of DRYness if it facilitated a solution I could understand.

Comment: Maybe I should be thinking about using something like this: http://mceachen.github.io/closure_tree/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance) and [HABTM](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) could solve your problem.

You'd like to design something like the following:

[image: Car parts and lists diagram]

A `Car` can have many parts and a `Part` can be a single `PartItem` or a `PartList`. And a `PartList` can have many `PartItem`.

In rails it would be something like:

```
# migrations
class CreateCars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cars do |t|
      t.string :model
    end
  end
end

class CreateParts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :parts do |t|
      t.string :type # STI
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end

class CreateCarsParts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cars_parts do |t|
      t.integer :car_id
      t.integer :part_id
    end
  end
end

class CreatePartListsPartItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :part_lists_part_items do |t|
      t.integer :part_list_id
      t.integer :part_item_id
    end
  end
end

# models
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parts
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cars
end

class PartItem < Part
  has_and_belongs_to_many :part_lists,
                          join_table: :part_lists_part_items
end

class PartList < Part
  has_and_belongs_to_many :part_items,
                          join_table: :part_lists_part_items
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's great. Should work. I'd like to quibble a bit, though. The assertion that "Part" can be a single PartItem or a PartList" is accurate in terms of modeling, but is nonsense linguistically. I suppose it shouldn't matter in terms of getting to a solution for my issue. I have been tripped-up by rails before when linguistics become non-sensical. It's a warning bell for me when I can't make simple sentences that describe relations.  I will keep reminding myself that a "part" can be either an item or a list of items, but I wish it had another name. Either way, thanks for your excellent answer.

Comment: I disagree about "nonsense linguistically", you would order an engine, not a crankshaft, pistons, oilpan, etc... Many car parts are simply collections of other parts.

Comment: I am not a linguistic expert, so I may be off base here.  It strikes me that a "part" is a tangible item.  It's a stretch to also say a "part" is the same thing as a "list of parts"

Comment: Having since learned about STI, I guess I can say it this way.  Naming a table that makes use of STI can be a challenge for me.  STI tables represent (contain) multiple similar, but different,classes. Referencing such a table with a single name, almost by definition, must be done with some compromise of precision.

Comment: Or another, and maybe better, way to say it: "There is no realworld single word Super Class that describes both PartLists and PartItems.